# Type error: for p in permutations(a): TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python-2.7, permutation

Here is my code :

```
t=(int(input()))
from itertools import permutations
for i in range(0,t):
    a=input()
    sum=0
    count=0
    for p in permutations(a):
        sum=sum+int(''.join(p))
        count=count+1
    print(str(count)+" "+str(sum))
```

It's working fine in Python 3.0+x but not in python 2.7

Comment: You need to use `raw_input` in Python 2.x if you want the same behaviour as `input` in 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

```
t=(int(input()))
from itertools import permutations
for i in range(0,t):
    a=raw_input()
    sum=0
    count=0
    for p in permutations(a):
        sum=sum+int(''.join(p))
        count=count+1
    print(str(count)+" "+str(sum))
```

Change input to raw_input in line 4,
in python 2.x, input means integer and raw_input means str